# Is a console shim required when using Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I often see a shim like the following in JavaScript AMD modules to ensure **console** is available:

```
(function () {
    var f = function () { };
    if (!window.console) {
        window.console = {
            log: f, info: f, warn: f, debug: f, error: f
        };
    }
}());
```

Is this needed when using Dojo?

Looking through http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/debugging.html it seems Dojo is doing something similar by default?

Comment: I don't think so, If you see at the top it say that the document is **deprecated**. I have tried to search the dojo source but could not find something similar in the core dojo. There is a shim for console logging related to webworkers though (`dojo\tests\_base\loader\hostenv_webworkers\console.js`), which is similar to your code. This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) shows the support for `console.log` in browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo will already do this for you as long as `dojo/_base/kernel` is loaded.  (It is a dependency of a number of common modules, e.g. `lang`, `dom-construct`, and `on`.)

https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/1.10.4/_base/kernel.js#L153-L176